# Try to create a regex for exctracting website address from a string in java but can't do it properly

Tags: java, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract website address from a url using following code

```
public String getWebSiteAddress(String text)
    {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\\.)+[a-z]{2,3}\\b");

        //Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^http\\:/[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\\S*)?$");
        System.out.println("\\b([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\\.)+[a-z]{2,3}\\b");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        if(m.matches())
        {
            System.out.println("got it");
            return  m.group(0) ;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("ddnt get");
            return "";
        }


    }
```

turns out this code works flawlessly inside regexBuddy but in JAVA
can anyone help me what is the problem with my regex or should I change something in my regex according to java?

the website I want to extract is something like :

> http://intelweb.xyz.kycv.kk.jj/~u0082/jbvelweb2/

Comment: What about `.info` or `.museum` domains?

Comment: it doens't work with .info or 3+ characters do u have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the find() method of matcher.

```
public String getWebSiteAddress(String text)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\\.)+[a-z]{2,3}\\b");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("got it");
        return  m.group(1) ;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("didnt get");
        return "";
    }
}
```

Matches apparently only works if the entire string matches the regex.